# Слова "ад" и "рай"

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология русских слов "ад" и "рай"? По-латыни они звучат совершенно иначе, а откуда произошли в русском?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русский язык слово **АД** пришло из старославянского, а туда - из греческого. Ср.: Αίδης - 'Аид, бог преисподней' > 'преисподняя', 'ад'. Этимология имени Аид (на греческой почве) не вполне ясна, возможно от слова со значением 'невидимый' (='погруженный во мрак') (Из Историко-этимологического словаря П.Я.Черных).

Что касается слова **РАЙ**, то, по Фасмеру, оно, скорее всего, заимств. из др.-иранского., ср. авест. raу - "богатство, счастье", др.-инд. raу-, ras - "состояние, сокровище, богатство", rayis "дар, владение", которые родственны латинскому. rеs "дело, имущество", др.-инд. rati "дает, дарует". Кроме того, слово РАЙ родственно греческому παρτδείσος 'рай' - из др.-ир. pairidaeza-. Все это говорит, что слово имеет праиндоевропейские корни.